# mongodb: How to save date and create index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i would like to store a lot of data in the database. So I hope that I can use the index to do the filtering.

My current idea is, when I apply the index, mongodb only search for the data with the same index. So, it can save a lot time and resources.

Below is my data that i want to save into database

`{ "name": "Mr A","type": "Individual","country": "Nepal"}`

`{ "name": "Mr B","type": "Individual","country": "Singapore"}`

`{ "name": "Company C","type": "Corporate","country": "Singapore"}`

So when i save, **how do I create index** when i save the date?

```
const customer = new Customer({ "name": "Mr A","type": "Individual,"country": "Nepal"});

await customer.save()

const customer2 = new Customer({ "name": "Mr B","type": "Individual","country": "Singapore"});

await customer2.save()

const customer3 = new Customer({ "name": "Company C","type": "Corporate","country": "Singapore"});

await customer3.save()

// Create index now and how?

// hope to create index
```

So, when i do the search

```
const findCustomer = await Customer.find({type: "Individual"}).explain("executionStats")
```

I hope that, mongodb only  "totalDocsExamined" only 2 document instead of 3

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index using the **ensureIndexes()** method, you can create an index on the "type" field.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Define your schema
const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  country: String,
});

// Create an index on the 'type' field
customerSchema.index({ type: 1 });

// Create a model using the schema
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema);

// Now, save your documents
const customer = new Customer({ name: "Mr A", type: "Individual", country: "Nepal" });
await customer.save();

const customer2 = new Customer({ name: "Mr B", type: "Individual", country: "Singapore" });
await customer2.save();

const customer3 = new Customer({ name: "Company C", type: "Corporate", country: "Singapore" });
await customer3.save();

// Ensure the indexes are created
await Customer.ensureIndexes();

// Now, when you search for customers of a specific type, the index will be used
const findCustomer = await Customer.find({ type: "Individual" }).explain("executionStats");
console.log(findCustomer);
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no `Model.createIndex` in mongoose. There is a [Model.createIndexes()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.createIndexes()) but this tells the mongo driver to create indexes defined in the schema so indexes need to be defined at the schema level, not on the model.

Comment: @jQueeny Thank you for bringing that to my attention. I appreciate your understanding. Now, please check again as I have updated the answer.

Comment: That looks good. I'm not sure `Customer.ensureIndexes();` is needed as an index will be created as soon as the first document is saved but a good reference nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes can be defined on the path where you declare each property like so:

```js
const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  type: {
      type: String,
      index: true
  },
  country: String
});
```

Or you can define them on the schema like so:

```
const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  country: String
});
customerSchema.index({ type: 1 });
```

Be careful with the `type` property you have declared. In mongoose `type` has a [special meaning](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey) in a schema and can be the source of unexpected behaviour if you don't understand the data correctly.